# Difference between GET and FILTER in Django model layer

Tags: python, django

What is the difference, please explain them in laymen's terms with examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I don't know if you really need an example, it's quite easy:

- if you know it's one object that matches your query, use get. It will fail if it's more than one.
- otherwise use filter, which gives you a list of objects.

To be more precise:

- `MyTable.objects.get(id=x).whatever` gives you the `whatever` property of your object.

**get()** raises MultipleObjectsReturned if more than one object was found.
The MultipleObjectsReturned exception is an attribute of the model
class.

**get()** raises a DoesNotExist exception if an object wasn’t found for the
given parameters. This exception is also an attribute of the model class.

- `MyTable.objects.filter(somecolumn=x)` is not only usable as a list, but you can also query it again, something like `MyTable.objects.filter(somecolumn=x).order_by('date')`.
- The reason is that it's not actually a list, but a query object. You can iterate through it like through a list: `for obj in MyTable.objects.filter(somecolumn=x)`