# Difference between Django's filter() and get() methods

Tags: django

What is the difference between

```
mymodel=model.objects.get(name='pol')
```

and

```
mymodel=model.objects.filter(name='pol')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between GET and FILTER in Django model layer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541249/difference-between-get-and-filter-in-django-model-layer)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The [Django QuerySet docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) are very clear on this:

`get(**kwargs)¶`

> Returns the object matching the given
>   lookup parameters, which should be in
>   the format described in Field lookups.
>
> get() raises MultipleObjectsReturned
>   if more than one object was found. The
>   MultipleObjectsReturned exception is
>   an attribute of the model class.
>
> get() raises a DoesNotExist exception
>   if an object wasn't found for the
>   given parameters. This exception is
>   also an attribute of the model class.

`filter(**kwargs)`

> Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup parameters.

Basically use `get()` when you want to get **a single unique object**, and `filter()` when you want to get **all objects** that match your lookup parameters.

Comment: Answer is useful and I missed few things about get() that Sdolan told here

Answer (score 15):

Note that behind the scenes the django get() method runs the filter() method, but checks that the filter results set is exactly one record

Answer (score 11):

Also, on a side note, assuming pol is not available:

```
if mymodel=model.objects.get(name='pol').exists()==False:
   print "Pol does not exist"
```

you will get:
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'exists'

but:

```
if mymodel=model.objects.filter(name='pol').exists()==False:
   print "Pol does not exist"
```

you will get: Pol does not exist.

I.e. If you want to run some code depending on whether a single object can be found, use filter. For some reason exists() works on QuerySet but not the specific object returned with get.

Answer (score 6):

get() returns an object that matches lookup criterion.

filter() returns a QuerySet that matche lookup criterion.

For example, the following

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2006)
```

is equivalent to

```
Entry.objects.all().filter(pub_date__year=2006)
```

which means filter() is slightly expensive operation if the model class has a large number of objects, whereas get() is direct approach.

source: [Django making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)

Answer (score 4):

Another difference:

Because 'get' returns an object, the method 'update' cannot be called on the object; except a model method (which shouldn't be done, to avoid overriding), was written.

However, querying with 'filter', gives you the ability to update a preferred record.

e.g: say a model; 'Product' exists in your app; then you could do thus:

```
old_product_name = Product.objects.filter(product_name="green-peas")
old_product_name.update(product_name="skewed-peas")
```

That of course, isn't possible when you query with 'get'.

Answer (score 1):

Django's get and filter methods are commonly used by django models, and are distinguished here.

Define 2 models.

```
class Student(models.Model):
 Name = models.CharField('name', max_length=15, default='')
 Age = models.CharField('age', max_length=15, default='')


class Book(models.Model):
 student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
```

A.django get method:

1. django's get method is to get a matching result from the database, return an object, if the record does not exist, it will report an error. For example, if there is a record in my database, the value of the record name is django123, I use student = Student . objects . get ( name = ’ django123 ’ ),
   returns a record object, which you can view through student . _ _ dict _ _, which returns a dictionary form, {' key ' : valeus}, key is the field The name, while values ​​are the contents of the value.
   Using the get method to query a record that does not exist in the database, the program will report an error.
   For example: student = Student . objects . get ( name = ’ django ’ ), obviously this 'django ' does not exist in the database, it will report an error.
2. If you use django's get to get the data of the associated table, if the data of the key table is more than 2, it will report an error.
   If there is a record in the student table:

> ```
> d name age
> 1 python 24
>
> Book table:
>
> id student_id
> 1 1
> 2 1
> ```

> student = Student.objects.get(name='python')

> book = Book.objects.get(student)

The result will be reported because the book table has 2 records that match the student table.

Two.django filter method:

1. django's filter method is to get a matching result from the database, return a list of objects, if the record does not exist, it will return [ ].
   If the database has a record, the value of the record name is python123, using student = Student . objects .filter ( name = ’ python123 ’ ). Returning student is a list of objects. It can be seen that student [ 0 ] is the same as the student returned by the get method above.
2. If you use django's get to get the data of the associated table, no matter how many records in the associated table, no error will be reported.
   django In addition to the powerful model, forms and templates are also very powerful.
   filter has the function of caching data. The first time you query the database and generate the cache, the next time you call the filter method, you can directly get the cached data, and the get method is directly queried every time in database.

Answer (score 1):

```
mymodel=model.objects.get(name='pol')
# OR
mymodel=model.objects.filter(name='pol')
```

Case 1: Suppose we have only one record that matches the name field *pol*.

- get() will return on single objects whereas filter() will also return a single object in the list.

Case 2: Suppose we have more than one records that match the name field *pol*.

- get() will raise MultipleObjectsReturned but in the case of filter(), it will return a list of objects.

Case 3: Suppose we have no record found that matches the name field *pol*.

- get() raises a DoesNotExist exception but in the case of filter(), it will return an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

if you know it's one object that matches your query, use "get". It will fail if it's more than one and gives the error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in    get
return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 407, in get
(self.model._meta.object_name, num))
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Poll -- it returned 2!
```

Otherwise use "filter", which gives you a list of objects.

Answer (score -3):

### Model = Employee

Employee : name,age,loc
Get:

> > Employee.objects.get(id=1)
> >        
> >     It will through error if given object is not there
> >     Filter :
> >     Employee.objects.filter(id=1)
> >       ]>
> >     It will return empty Queryset if given object is not there