# Get model ID correctly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I got two models. One model for building main menu, another one - for Articles. Every Article have `ForeignKey`to link it to main menu item.

I can't figured out, how can I show on page `Article`, that linked to `menuItem` Model and how to use `menuItem` model's `alias` field for URL address?

My model `menuItem`:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from django.db import models

    class MainMenuItem(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            db_table = "menu_item"  
        title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        alias = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

My model `Article`:

```
    class Article(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            db_table = "article"

        menu = models.ForeignKey(MainMenuItem, blank = True, null = True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.menu) or u''

        def __str__(self):
            return self.menu
```

My `views.py`

```
    def menu_builder(request, alias):
        findId = MainMenuItem.objects.????
        elements = {
            'menuItems': MainMenuItem.objects.all(),
            'article': Article.objects.get(id=??????),
        }
        return render_to_response('myview.html', elements)
```

My `urls.py`:

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^(?P<alias>.+?)/$', 'menuItem.views.menu_builder'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just filter by the alias on `MainMenuItem` then get all articles that related to that `MainMenuItem`:

```
def menu_builder(request, alias):
    main_menu_item = MainMenuItem.objects.get(alias=alias)
    elements = {
            'menuItems': main_menu_item,
            'articles': main_menu_item.article_set.all(),
        }
    return render_to_response('myview.html, elements)
```

Django doc about [related object lookup using `_set`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

**Edit:**

I should have been using `objects.get()` previously, but was using `objects.filter()` which is wrong. The difference is that you should get exactly one item so that you could get related articles to that object. If you use `filter`, you would end up having a queryset, but then it doesn't make sense to check related objects on multiple objects, hence the error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'article_set'`.

Beware that you should have distinct `alias` for `MainMenuItem` objects, otherwise `get()` would throw an exception "Multiple objects returned".

Comment: Hi! And thanks for an answer. I tried to use your code, but got `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'article_set'` I tried to make related name, but still got same error...

Comment: I made a mistake and corrected my answer. I try to explain as much as I can because I don't want to spoon-feed with answers. Please check this about the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods