# Django Get and Filter

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a design question on django.

Can someone explain to me why the Django `ORM` 'get' doesn't return a `queryset`?
To the best of my understanding, a `queryset` should/is the result of a db query. With that logic, isn't a `get` query a `queryset`?

Also, from my research towards this question, I found out the `get` query calls the model `manager` while the `queryset` doesn't.

Is there a reasoning behind all of this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Django's filter() and get() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods)

Answer (score 0):

From django documentation [queryset api reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get)

> get() raises MultipleObjectsReturned if more than one object was found. The MultipleObjectsReturned exception is an attribute of the model class.

While filter returns a set of instances that match the lookups kwargs in an instance of `QuerySet`

For example:

```
A=Model.objects.get(id=1)
B=Model.objects.filter(id=1)
print(isinstance(A,Model))  # True
print(isinstance(B,QuerySet))  # True
```

#### Get sql >>

```
select * from public.app_model where id=1;
```

#### Filter sql >>

```
select * from public.app_model where id=1;
```

but at implementation `get` must return an instance, if the query returns more than 1 row it will raise `MultipleObjectsReturned` yet filter not, it will return all the rows in Model class instance form

BTW, Both use the cache property