# Django query using datetime flter

Tags: django

In my (Post) model I have

```
published = models.DateField(null=True)
```

My urls include the year/month/day eg

```
/post/category-1/2017/11/06/some-post/
```

which I am capturing through kwargs in my urls.py

In my view my query is

```
model =   Post.objects.get(slug=kwargs['slug'],published__year=kwargs['year'],
published__month=kwargs['month'],published__day=kwargs['day'])
```

However, this is not working. The only date element which works is for year. I've read some posts here which talk about unsetting USE_TZ in settings.py which is obviously not a solution.

I have tried using a DateTime field as well, but that makes no difference.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: can you mysql timezone are loaded https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

Comment: Can you post the relevant pattern from urls.py?

Comment: "Not working" how? What happens?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for getting back. Daniel, I get a "does not exist" error - post matching query does not exist", This only happens when I add in the month (and the date) to the query. The url pattern is url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',views.ModuleDetail.as_view(),name='detail'). Robert please let me check on your comment and I will come back

Comment: Hi, I don't have any problems on the live (Ubuntu) server, only on my local machine (WAMP on Windows 10). It must be the mysql timeszones. Many thanks for your help - will look into this in more detail.

Comment: Hi, I now realise that the problem in terms of the multiple results was being caused elsewhere in the code (my breadcrumb). I have commented this out and all is good - many thanks for helping out much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at :

```
import datetime
sDate = '2017/11/06'
dtDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(sDate, "%Y/%m/%d")
models =   Post.objects.filter(slug=kwargs['slug'],published=dtDate)
```

But this implies that you have the correct value in sDate. So as kristab requested pls post your url pattern

Comment: Hi, I have done this, and still get the error "does not exist .. Post matching query does not exist"

Comment: have you cross checked that the expected data is in the database ?

Comment: Hi, yes, we have a date field for this post which should give the expected result eg 2017-11-06. I think the issue is the mysql time zones, which I need to look into (will get back on this)

Comment: I don't have any problems on the live (Ubuntu) server, only on my local machine (WAMP on Windows 10). It must be the mysql timeszones. Many thanks for your help - will look into this in more detail.

Comment: I think DateFields do not need the timezone. 01.01.1999 means the same in New York and in Paris. Try to manually select the row that you expect with the mysql utilities

Comment: I havent changed anything but now I'm getting 2 results and hence an error for objects.get() where I have a post with the same slug (but different dates!). When I run the same query in my shell it's fine! Here are sample kwargs {'category_slug': 'post-cat-1', 'year': '2017', 'month': '10', 'day': '16', 'slug': 'post-1'}. Not sure why I'm getting different results!

Comment: `objects.get()` and `objects.filter()`do have different results see `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods` do you get the 2 results with filter() ? get() should raise `MultipleObjectsReturned`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158322/discussion-between-newfoundland-and-mbieren).

Comment: Hi, I now realise that the problem in terms of the multiple results was being caused elsewhere in the code (my breadcrumb). I have commented this out and all is good - many thanks for helping out much appreciated.