# Why does get and filter work differently for annotated fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a get_queryset in a custom Manager for a Model that renames fields:

```
class Manager:
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(Manager, self).get_queryset().values(renamed_field=F('original_field'))
```

Why is it that I can do a .filter on the renamed field but when I do a .get I need to use the original field name?

This works:

```
Model.objects.filter(renamed_field='Test')
```

But this errors out with matching query does not exist:

```
Model.objects.get(renamed_field='Test')
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) about Querysets:

> Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and
>   generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No
>   database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate
>   the queryset.

When you call the `get` method, you hit the database. This explains why you get the error about no matching query.

Comment: Is there a way to annotate a get method?

Comment: If you are looking for a single object, you could do a filter (which works with annotations) and then use `first()`. For example `Model.objects.filter(renamed_field='Test').first()`

Comment: But filter followed by first hits the DB for all records before slicing the results in python?

Comment: Yes, but there is a difference between `get` and `filter` (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods) You are able to do annotations, rename fields etc. because you are dealing with a QuerySet, whereas a `get` goes straight to the DB. You cannot perform high level manipulations like you can with QuerySet objects.