# Django, attributes of get and filter queryset method

Tags: django

*This may be possible duplication of question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46439518/10515390)* which says,

get() returns an object that matches lookup criterion.

filter() returns a QuerySet that matches lookup criterion.

Consider below model,

```
  class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    head = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

When I try to query the authors list based on specific Entry objects got error as  attached below

[image]

**Why don't the filter queryset have no attribute '**authors**' ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it’s a set of models, not a model (even if there’s only one model in there). You need to extract it out of the queryset by iteration or slicing.

If you’re only interested in one instance then just stick to objects.get(). Objects.filter is used for querying more than one object.

Note: .all() just gets everything from db and using it on already filtered queryset just brings you the same thing.

Comment: I have looped through the queryset filtered and obtained the result. Thanks