# Django - Not able to access the data from model

Tags: python, django

I am currently using django 3.2 and when I try to print the models data in the views it throws the following error

My views look like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from user.models import Student

@login_required
def home(request):
   user = request.user
   student_user = Student.objects.all()
   student_users = []
   for user in student_user:
      student_users.append(user.User.username)
   stu_user = request.user.username
   student_list_set = set(student_users)



  if stu_user in student_list_set:
    data =  Student.objects.filter(User=request.user)
    print(data.Name)

    params = {
        'data':student,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/student/dashboard.html', params)
```

When I try to print the print the data.name. It throws the following error

```
AttributeError at /
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Name'
```

My models.py file looks like this

```
class Student(models.Model):
 User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 Profile = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_student_profile_to, default = 
 'defaults/student_profile.png')
 class_choices = (('1','1'), ('2','2'), ('3','3'), ('4','4'),('5','5'),('6','6'),('7','7'),('8','8'), 
 ('9','9'),('10','10'))
 Class = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=class_choices)
 section_choices = (('A','A'),('B','B'),('C','C'),('D','D'),('E','E'))
 Section = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=section_choices)
 Roll = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
 Number = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
 is_banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)

 def __str__(self):
     return self.Name + " of " + self.Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can only exist one student per user, the simplier way of doing it is like this:

```py
student = Student.objects.get(User=request.user)
print(student.name)
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods) to understand when to user `.get()` and when to use `.filter()`.

Answer (score 1):

data variable is a queryset, not a Student object, so you should access like a list.

If you are sure that

```
data =  Student.objects.filter(User=request.user)
```

returns one element you can print like this:

```
print(data[0].Name)
```