# why Django filter giving me this error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user_id'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

When I am using this queryset  I am not getting any error and it's returning the user id

```
UserProfile.objects.get(forget_password_token=forget_password_token)
print(user.user_id)

>>>19
```

But when I am using this queryset `UserProfile.objects.filter(forget_password_token=forget_password_token)` why I am getting this error  `QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user_id'`

what is difference between get and filter in Django ? why not  working filter method here?

When user putting wrong code in input fields then it's rising this error
`UserProfile matching query does not exist.`

Comment: Also see [Difference between Django's filter() and get() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods)

Comment: ```get()``` will return you a single object where you can access all the attributes of your object but ```filter()``` will return queryset to access your object from queryset you need to iterate it oe you can use ```.first()``` method to get first object like this ```UserProfile.objects.filter(forget_password_token=forget_password_token).first()``` and than you can access ```user.user_id```

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat I read the question but I didn't understood properly about concept of get and filter so I post question here.

Comment: @Ankit Tiwari Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With .get() the return the instance of the object found so you can check directly user_id.
With .filter() the rturn is a query set object contain all instances of ogject found (you can compare it to a list of results with some différences as it's an object type Queryset)
So if you Want to check user_id, you have first to iterate all élément of the queryset

```
test = UserProfile.objects.filter(forget_password_token=forget_password_token)
for result in test:
    print(test.user_id)
```

Another way can be to return the result in a list with .values_list()

```
test = UserProfile.objects.filter(forget_password_token=forget_password_token).values_list('user_id')
```