# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, html, django

This is the page that I'm trying to work out. If the update is clicked, the filled-in details should be updated in a MySql database called TL.

[image]

But while clicking update, it's throwing the following error:  AttributeError at /add/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

[image]

The following is Views.py file in Django where I had put code for add:

```
    def add(request):
    ad = TL.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        TL_Name = request.POST.get('TL_Name')
        Proj_name = request.POST.get('Proj_name')
        Deadline = request.POST.get('Deadline')
        ad.TL_Name = TL_Name
        ad.Proj_name = Proj_name
        ad.Deadline = Deadline
        ad.save()
        return redirect("/operations")
    return render(request, 'operations.html', {"name": ad, 'b': ad})
```

The following is the urls.py file:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('adminlogin/', views.adminlogin),
    path('operations/', views.operations),
    path('approve/<int:pk>', views.approval),
    path('decline/<int:pk>/', views.delete),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', views.edit),
    path('add/', views.add),
    path('tlist/', views.approved_tlist)
]
```

The following is the operations.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Team Leaders</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>List of Team Leaders</h1>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>TL_Name</th>
        <th>Proj_name</th>
        <th>Proj_Status</th>
        <th>Deadline</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    {% for i in name %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{i.TL_Name}}</td>
        <td>{{i.Proj_name}}</td>
        <td>{{i.Proj_Status}}</td>
        <td>{{i.Deadline}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/approve/{{i.id}}">Approve</a>
            <a href="/decline/{{i.pk}}">Decline</a>
            <a href="/edit/{{i.pk}}">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<br>
<br>
{% if a %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>TL_Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="TL_Name" value="{{a.TL_Name}}">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Proj_Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Proj_name" value="{{a.Proj_name}}">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Proj_Status</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{a.Proj_Status}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Deadline</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Deadline" value="{{a.Deadline}}">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Update">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
{% endif %}
<tr>
    <a href="/add/">Add</a>
</tr>
{% if b %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>TL_Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="TL_Name" value="{{b.TL_Name}}">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Proj_Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Proj_name" value="{{b.Proj_name}}">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Proj_Status</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{b.Proj_Status}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Deadline</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Deadline" value="{{b.Deadline}}">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Update">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to sort out this error. Thank you in advance...

Comment: I got this error when filtering an object with only PK, the solution was to use `yourModel.objects.get(pk=pk)`, instead of `yourModel.objects.filter(pk=pk)`, because filter returns a QuerySet, while get returns an object. The error says it can't save a QuerySet, so you want an object instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods

Answer (score 2):

```
    ad = TL.objects.all()
```

is assigning the queryset of all TL to ad

```
    ad.TL_Name = TL_Name
    ad.Proj_name = Proj_name
    ad.Deadline = Deadline
    ad.save()
```

This code will not work as this isn't a single instance of a model.

If you want update all objects of TL you can use update

```
   ad = TL.objects.update(TL_Name=TL_Name, Proj_name=Proj_name, Deadline=Deadline)
```

or use TL.objects.first() or TL.objects.get(id=id_you_want)

to get an individual instance of the model and then use

```
    ad.TL_Name = TL_Name
    ad.Proj_name = Proj_name
    ad.Deadline = Deadline
    ad.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You first set `ad = TL.objects.all()` This returns all your Model objects. Then later on in your code you're trying to save `ad` to your database. That won't work, and Django is telling you that. You're trying to save a queryset.

Answer (score 0):

*You have this error because you apply a `.save()` method on a queryset, that is wrong.* Instead you need to call `.save()` on a object instance like this:

```
def add(request):
    # ad = TL.objects.all()  Not usefull here
    context = {}
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        TL_Name = request.POST.get('TL_Name')
        Proj_name = request.POST.get('Proj_name')
        Deadline = request.POST.get('Deadline')
        
        # Create a new TL instance here (Note that with class.objects.create() we don't need to call save())
        new_tl = TL.objects.create(TL_Name=TL_Name, Proj_name=Proj_name, Deadline=Deadline)
        # Update the context data
        context = ['b'] = new_tl
        
        return redirect("/operations")
    # Retrieve all TL objects and add to context
    context['name'] = TL.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'operations.html', context)
```