# to check user password is correct in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication

I'm writing a custom login functionality in the Django rest framework. But I can't check if the password is correct or not.

```
class LoginView(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    username=request.data["username"]
    password=request.data["password"]
    user=User.objects.filter(username=username)
    if user is None:
        return Response({"response":"No User exist"})
    if user.check_password(password):
        return Response({"response":"correct Password"})
    return Response({"data":"done"})
```

the problem is check_password function is not working.Is there any right way to do that or do I miss something in between?

Comment: `filter()` will always return a QuerySet. If you want to get one user, use `get()` or any other method that returns one object.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this one:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('Home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Invalid Credential') 
            return redirect('login')
    else:        
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

pass this in your template:

```
<div class="text-center text-danger">
     {% for message in messages %}
          <h5>{{ message }}</h5>
      {% endfor %}
   <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password

You need to compare the plain password in request.data["password"], with the password of the user in the DB.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class LoginView(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    username=request.data["username"]
    password=request.data["password"]
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is None:
        return Response({"response":"No User exist"})
    else:
        return Response({"response":"correct Password"})
```

Comment: You are right, my bad, i update de answer in order to use authenticate function.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by making an updation, I changed the filter() to get(), as filter() will return a query set but get () will return an object.

Updated Code :

```
class LoginView(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    username=request.data["username"]
    password=request.data["password"]
    user=User.objects.get(username=username)
    if user is None:
        return Response({"response":"No User exist"})
    if not user.check_password(password):
        return Response({"response":"incorrect Password"})
    return Response({"data":"done"})
```

If anyone still couldn't understand the difference of both functions (get and filter). Please check out the link [Difference between Django's filter() and get() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods).

Thanks everyone who helps for the solution.