# Django filter vs get in models

Tags: django-models

Im a newbie to Django and would like to understand what is the difference between filter vs get

Get

```
Entry.objects.get(id__exact=14)
```

Filter

```
Entry.objects.filter(id__exact=14)
```

What difference the above statement makes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541249/difference-between-get-and-filter-in-django-model-layer

Comment: Also Duplicate of [Difference between Django's `filter()` and `get()` methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between GET and FILTER in Django model layer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541249/difference-between-get-and-filter-in-django-model-layer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Django's filter() and get() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods)

Comment: Also, the answers to the earlier questions are of better quality than the ones given here...

Comment: I wish google was as good at finding these previous answers as you guys were. This page is the top hit in 2020

Answer (score 13):

the `get` only brings an element that is equal to what you're looking for but the `filter` brings everything related to that item you want.

filter returns many things found.
get returns only one thing to what you're looking for

for example:

GET

```
Task.objects.get(id=1,status=1)
```

Filter

```
Groups.objects.filter(user=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know it's one object that matches your query, use `get`. It will fail if it's more than one, and gives the error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in         get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 407, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, num))
    MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Poll -- it returned 2!
```

Otherwise use `filter`, which gives you a list of objects.

Answer (score 2):

Basically use `get` when you want to get a single unique object, and filter when you want to get all objects that match your lookup parameters

```
 __data = User.objects.get(is_active=1).exclude(id=id)
```

> Error:get() returned more than one User -- it returned 19!,
>   Type:`<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.MultipleObjectsReturned'>`

------successful-------

```
__data = User.objects.filter(is_active=1).exclude(id=id)
```

-------successful------

[Check the Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter)

Answer (score 2):

To add to what others have said... (get returns exactly 1 record, while filter returns a set), an important thing to note is the *type* of the results.

get() returns an object, while filter returns a queryset type. This means you can do something like

```
age = User.objects.get(name="Ryan").age
```

Whereas if you were using filter, you'd need to do a couple extra steps:

```
ages = User.Objects.filter(name="ryan").values('age')
for user_age in ages:
    print(user_age)
```

The important thing to note is that filter returns an iterable type with a values() method dictating which fields you want. Get simply returns an object with the fields as attributes, so it is much simpler to get the data you need.

Comment: I was about to upvote your answer, but there's a mistake in it: `get` does NOT return a queryset - it returns a single object. It is `filter` that returns a `queryset`, which is, as you correctly point out, an iterable.

Comment: I think you have a logic error in the second code
```python
ages = User.Objects.filter(name="ryan").values('age')
for user_age in users:
    print(user_age)
```
it should be
```python
ages = User.Objects.filter(name="ryan").values('age')
for user_age in ages:
    print(user_age)
```