# Django Model.objects.get - object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building a Django app with a user model. the model:
models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

views.py

```
class UserProfile(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
```

when going to the url /profile i get an error:

'User' object is not iterable

I validated that i have a User in the database with id = 1 and also that  self.request.user.id is int(1)

appreciate any insight

I tried to get the user profile data from the object user.
i was expecting to get a result with the user serialized i.e
{id: 1, first_name="X", last_name="Y"}
i actually got a response with 'User' object is not iterable

Comment: in `get_queryset` reutrn `User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)`, use filter to get all records [django-filter-vs-get-in-models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251401/django-filter-vs-get-in-models)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ModelViewSet` is not suited for this task, since a simple GET will return a *list*, perhaps a list with one element, but a list. You only retrieve a single element if you add a `/pk` suffix in the URL.

You can work with a `RetrieveAPIView`:

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView


class UserProfile(RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to return a queryset that can be iterated over in order to correct this mistake. To accomplish this, you can encapsulate the returned object in a list as seen below:

```
def get_queryset(self):
   return User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
```

This will produce a queryset that can be iterated over and contains a single User object with the given id.

Comment: Thanks Papan, this is what I did initially but this return a list with a single object while I wanted to return just the object.

Comment: Alright, try using RetrieveAPIView instead