# MultipleObjectsReturned with get_or_create

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm writing a small django command to copy data from a json API endpoint into a Django database. At the point I actually create the objects, with `obj, created = model.objects.get_or_create(**filters)`, I am getting a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error. This is surprising to me, because my understanding of `get_or_create` is that if I try to create an object that already exists, it will just 'get' it instead.

I'm not certain about the integrity of the database I'm cloning, but even if there are multiple identical objects in it, when I load them into my local Django database, shouldn't get_or_create make it so that I never get more than one copy?

Can anybody explain this? I'm happy to give more specifics, I just didn't want to bog the reader down.

Comment: `get` search for an `unique` element if there are more `elements` it raises the error `MultipleObjectsReturned`, filter search for a lot of `elements` and returns a `list` of them.

Comment: A comparative is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541249/difference-between-get-and-filter-in-django-model-layer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the name implies, `get_or_create` `model.objects.get()`s or `model.objects.create()`s.

It's conceptually equivalent to:

```
try:
   model.objects.get(pk=1)
except model.DoesNotExist:
   model.objects.create(pk=1)
```

The source is where you find definitive answers to these types of questions. Hint: search `def get_or_create`.
As you can see, this function only catches `DoesNotExist` in the try/except.

```
def get_or_create(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Looks up an object with the given kwargs, creating one if necessary.
    Returns a tuple of (object, created), where created is a boolean
    specifying whether an object was created.
    """
    assert kwargs, \
            'get_or_create() must be passed at least one keyword argument'
    defaults = kwargs.pop('defaults', {})
    lookup = kwargs.copy()
    for f in self.model._meta.fields:
        if f.attname in lookup:
            lookup[f.name] = lookup.pop(f.attname)
    try:
        self._for_write = True
        return self.get(**lookup), False
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:
```

Comment: Right, my question was really more a thinking-through-it type than anything else. I see that `get_or_create` only catches `DoesNotExist`. But shouldn't it `self.get(**lookup)` if it DOES exist? If so, how could my script ever create the second object--thus how could I get the `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception?

Comment: @bepetersn you could get a duplicate depending on how you're populating the query kwargs (this has actually happened to me): `get_or_create(name=foo), get_or_create(name=foo, bar=bar), get_or_create(name=foo) # multiple`

Comment: Ah, I see! So I created two different objects (b/c of different numbers of params) with `create()`, then when I tried to `get()` using only specific enough parameters to narrow down the search to those two objects, I get an error.

So, in essence, `get(**params)` is literally only filtering the database. Sort of like a `select-where` SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks again for sticking with me and helping me figure that out, @Yuji

Comment: @Bepetersn, good find - exactly. Getting or creating with more params will cause duplicates of a single parameter. NP man!

Answer (score 29):

### Example code

Imagine you have the following model:

```
class DictionaryEntry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    definition = models.TextField(null=True, blank=False)
```

and the following code:

```
obj, created = DictionaryEntry.objects.get_or_create(
    name='apple', definition='some kind of fruit')
```

### `get_or_create`

In case you have not seen the [code for `get_or_create`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8f30556329b64005d63b66859a74752a0b261315/django/db/models/query.py#L449-L460):

```
 # simplified
 def get_or_create(cls, **kwargs):
     try:
         instance, created = cls.get(**kwargs), False
     except cls.DoesNotExist:
         instance, created = cls.create(**kwargs), True
     return instance, created
```

### about webservers...

Now imagine that you have a webserver with `2` worker processes that both have their own **concurrent access** to the database.

```
 # simplified
 def get_or_create(cls, **kwargs):
     try:
         instance, created = cls.get(**kwargs), False # <===== nope not there...
     except cls.DoesNotExist:
         instance, created = cls.create(**kwargs), True
     return instance, created
```

If the timing goes right (or wrong depending on how you want to phrase this), both processes can do the lookup and not find the item. They may both create the item. Everything is fine...

### `MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one KeyValue -- it returned 2!`

Everything is fine... until you call `get_or_create` a third time, "third time is a charm" they say.

```
 # simplified
 def get_or_create(cls, **kwargs):
     try:
         instance, created = cls.get(**kwargs), False # <==== kaboom, 2 objects.
     except cls.DoesNotExist:
         instance, created = cls.create(**kwargs), True
     return instance, created
```

### `unique_together`

How could you solve this? Maybe enforce a constraint at the database level:

```
class DictionaryEntry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    definition = models.TextField(null=True, blank=False)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'definition'),)
```

back to the function:

```
 # simplified
 def get_or_create(cls, **kwargs):
     try:
         instance, created = cls.get(**kwargs), False
     except cls.DoesNotExist:
         instance, created = cls.create(**kwargs), True # <==== this handles IntegrityError
     return instance, created
```

Say you have the same race as before, and they both did not find the item and proceed to the insert; doing so they will start a transaction and one of them is going to win the race while the other will see an `IntegrityError`.

### mysql ?

The example uses a `TextField`, which for `mysql` translates to a `LONGTEXT` (in my case). Adding the `unique_together` constraint fails the `syncdb`.

> `django.db.utils.InternalError: (1170, u"BLOB/TEXT column 'definition' used in key specification without a key length")`

So, no luck, you may have to deal with `MultipleObjectsReturned` manually.

- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2495
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12579
- http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/db/transactions.html#using-a-high-isolation-level
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

#### possible solutions

- It may be possible to replace the `TextField` with a `CharField`.
- It may be possible to add a `CharField` which may be a strong hash of the `TextField`, that you can compute in `pre_save` and use in a `unique_together`.

Answer (score 4):

Another situation that could cause MultipleObjectsReturned error with get_or_create() API seems to be if there are multiple threads calling this API at the same time with the same set of query parameters.

Solely relying on try... catch... to create a unique row in Python wouldn't work. If you are trying to use this API, I think you should have a matching uniqueness constraint on the appropriate columns in the database.

See: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12579

Answer (score 2):

Warning

This method is atomic assuming that the database enforces uniqueness of the keyword arguments (see unique or unique_together). If the fields used in the keyword arguments do not have a uniqueness constraint, concurrent calls to this method may result in multiple rows with the same parameters being inserted.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create